# How to dynamic access the enum

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an enum and I want to access to it dynamically. I'm not sure if it's possible or not.

```
enum EventType {
  earthquake,
  flood,
  fire
}

var event = "fire";

var mytype = EventType.event
```

You see, what I'm trying to achieve. Is it possible to access the enum like that (using a variable like `mytype`)

Comment: You can have a function, are a hashmap that matches strings and enum values.

Comment: @mana you want EventType.fire? like fire?

Comment: yes that's right @RavindraS.Patil

Comment: @mana check my below answer

Comment: I was hoping something like `var mytype = EventType.$(event)`  which use the value of variable event to match its member variable.  So what I got is `EventType.fire` because the value of event variable is fire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add this to your enum

```
  static EventType? fromName(String? name) {
    return values
        .firstWhereOrNull((e) => e.name == name);
  }
```

then this could work:

```
var event = "fire";

var mytype = EventType.fromName(event);
```

Note, using `firstWhereOrNull` requires

```
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';
```

Comment: thanks mate, I use your solution and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

**Your Enum:**

```
enum EventType {
  earthquake,
  flood,
  fire
}
```

Just print it:

```
print( EventType.fire.name);
```

Output: `fire`

Other Way:

```
void main() {
  const day = EventType.Fire;
  print(day.text);
}

enum EventType {
  Earthquake("earthquake"),
  Flood("flood"), 
  Fire("fire");
  

  const EventType(this.text);
  final String text;
}
```